# jquery help: Hiding submit button after sent for processing and change the action attribute of form

Tags: jquery, form-submit, onsubmit

So here is the problem I am facing. Any help is very much appreciated.

I have a form which has a text box and a submit button. The process-page.php has a php script that checks my database for userinformation and it returns the processed data.

```
<form id="myform" aciton="process-page.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="checkinfo" name="checkinfo" />
    <input type="submit" value="check info" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Now when the user enters the information in the text box and clicks on the submit button I use ajax to send the information to process-page.php and display the data without having to load the page.

The data I get back using ajax contains a sumit button (payment button) as well.

This is the response I get from process-page.php

```
//html information along with payment button.
<h2>The user is currently available. Make a payment to join hands with the user.</h2>
<input type="submit" id="payment" value="make payment" />
```

The problem is, I have 2 submit buttons, one next to text box which has a form action="process-page.php" and the other submit button(payment button) which is got as an response from process-page.php

Now what I want to do is, with the help of jquery I need to hide the submit button when the user submits the form.

Will this code work?

```
$("#myfrom").submit(function(){
    //perform validation so that no numbers are entered.
    if(does not match){
        alert();
        return false;
    }
    //THe above performs the validation

    Now is this the correct method to hide submit button?

    if(true){
        $("submit").hide();
    }

});
```

I want to know if this is the correct way to hide submit button on performing validation and if everything is validated the form is submitted and then submit button is hidden.

Now I would get another submit button(payment button) and I want the form action atrribute to be changed like this.

```
<form id="myform" aciton="make-payments.php" method="post">

Does, using this code works?

$("#form").attr('action', 'make-payments.php');
```

Will this change the action attribut. Do help me.

Comment: where is the ajax part? you can use `beforeSend` and `ajaxSuccess` methods.

Comment: the whole code looks okay... why you don't just try it?

Answer (score 0):

no, your hiding button code string will not work correctly.

check [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you are using wrong selector

Now you are using element selector, so all submit elements (you have none BTW), you must use id selector.

This will work:

```
$("#submit").hide();
```